# Handling just one exception code

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a question regarding `try/except`. I have an exception (lets call it `FooException`) that has a `status_code` in it. I want to handle the exception just if the `status_code` is 200.

I would do something like:

```
try:
    ...
except FooException as ex:
    if ex.status_code == 200:
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
```

Is there any other way or this one should go fine?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Catching specific exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531247/python-catching-specific-exception)

Answer (score 1):

that's fine... Have your `else:` simply call `raise`, and it will simply re-raise the current exception, to be handled elsewhere. (or `pass` if you simply want to ignore.)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks, I was sure that works, but didn't know if there was another (more pythonic) way.

Comment: You could always create a subclass of FooException, say, Foo200Exception have your code throw _that_ exception, but I'm all for readability and simplicity. Invent new stuff right before you need it & not before.