# Catch specific dictionary unpacking exception (TypeError) due to namespace/key name conflict

Tags: python

My question is: I want to reliably catch an error caused by the namespace conflict of multiple unpacked dictionaries. What is the canonical way? Searching didn't really reveal any help with this problem.

Say I have two dict-like variables with string keys I want to mash together. They represent objects that are similar namespaces so I want to make sure they don't have any name conflicts. I can do this, and conflicts give me a `TypeError`:

```
>>> d1 = dict(a=1)
>>> d2 = dict(a=2)
>>> format_args = dict(**d1, **d2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'
```

Excellent. So I may (naively) do something like this when constructing a namespace from two keyword-type arguments:

```
# test.py
from collections import OrderedDict as od

def kwargs_mash(kwargs1, kwargs2):
    try:
        # use unpacking to disallow multiple argslists to same member name
        args = od(**kwargs1, **kwargs2)
    except TypeError:
        key_conflict = next(k for k in kwargs1 if k in kwargs2)
        # more descriptive error message
        raise TypeError('Multiple argument sets provided under member name: {}.'.format(key_conflict)) from None
```

However, trying to unpack a non-mapping type of object also gives a `TypeError`:

```
>>> x=1
>>> d=dict(**x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not int
```

This is a problem because it is possible that the arguments passed to `kwargs_mash` are not `Mapping` objects, and my improved, more descriptive `TypeError` message will no longer be a good description of what happened.

My solution is below, and it works.

```
def kwargs_mash(kwargs1, kwargs2):
    try:
        # use unpacking to disallow multiple argslists to same member name
        args = od(**kwargs1, **kwargs2)
    except TypeError as exc:
        if 'multiple values for keyword argument' in str(exc):
            key_conflict = next(k for k in kwargs1 if k in kwargs2)
            # more descriptive error message
            raise TypeError('Multiple argument sets provided under member name: {}.'.format(key_conflict)) from None
        else:
            raise
```

However, [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531310/2437514) calls this approach "fragile", and I am inclined to agree.

> This is Python. There has to be a better way.

### Update

Maybe the best thing to do is just this:

```
def kwargs_mash(kwargs1, kwargs2):
    # ensure compatible arguments
    kwargs1, kwargs2 = od(**kwargs1), od(**kwargs2)
    # continue as before...
```

Comment: If you know so little about your arguments that you can't even predict what type they would be, you probably have to throw a whole lot of `isinstance` at it…

Comment: @deceze Might be right. I tend to try to stick to the zen of Python and avoid that stuff, but it's true that sometimes it is needed.

Comment: Why don't you implement the merging of the two mappings on your own? Then you will be able to detect the conflict reliably. I am proposing this option, since it doesn't seem to require more code than with your current solution

Comment: @Leon I was actually concerned I would do it in a naive way and end up with a slow implementation. But that might be what I need to do here.