# How do I catch only a specific error in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

Say I have a function that can produce a vast variety of errors.

I have a ValueError that I need to catch, a specific AttributeError, and then I also need to handle any other type of error.

```py
try:
  func()
except AttributeError as e:
  if "specific error text" in str(e):
    print("The specific AttributeError occurred")
  else:
    raise
except ValueError:
  print("A value error occurred")
except Exception as e:
  print("Another error occurred: {}".format(str(e)))
```

Problem: If `func()` bubbles an `AttributeError` that's not the specific one I'm looking for, in this case, it'll be re-raised and not handled how I want it to be handled (via the general `Exception` handler).

How do I force non-specific errors to be handled further down in the chain, without duplicating code from the `Exception` section into the `AttributeError` section?

Comment: is your `CustomError` a subclass of `AttributeError`?

Comment: The code you have there should work. Compare the string of `e` to the exception you're looking for. This should be what you're looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531247/python-catching-specific-exception

Comment: Yes, it works, but if `func()` creates an `AttributeError` that does not contain `"specific error text"`, then an exception is raised - the intent is that such an error would be handled by `Exception`

Comment: @AzatIbrakov It is not. I'll swap it out for ValueError, to avoid further confusion

Comment: can you provide a snippet of your `func` and `specific error text` example?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov `func()` is `getattr(COMMANDS, cmd.command).command(irc_c, msg, cmd)`, which checks a directory of IRC commands to see if the given string (`cmd.command`) is a match. If it is, it runs the `command` function of that class. If not, it elicits an `AttributeError`. `COMMANDS` is a `Command_Directory` object, and the specific text I'm checking for is  `"'Commands_Directory' object has no attribute"` (which would mean that the given command is not in the directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option you can process `AttributeError` and `ValueError` in one `try`-`except` block and all other `Exception`s on the top level like

```
try:
    try:
        func()
    except AttributeError as e:
        if "specific error text" in str(e):
            print("The specific AttributeError occurred")
        else:
            raise
    except ValueError:
        print("A value error occurred")
except Exception as e:
    print("Another error occurred: {}".format(str(e)))
```

this may look a bit ugly though, so we can extract inner `try`-`except` block in a separate function like

```
def func_with_expected_exceptions_handling():
    try:
        func()
    except AttributeError as e:
        if "specific error text" in str(e):
            print("The specific AttributeError occurred")
        else:
            raise
    except ValueError:
        print("A value error occurred")
```

and after that

```
try:
    func_with_expected_exceptions_handling()
except Exception as e:
    print("Another error occurred: {}".format(str(e)))
```

this doesn't save us from an actual nested structure, but it may come in handy if this kind of `func` processing arises in other places.

BTW, I don't think checking for a specific error message in exception is a good idea, we need a little bit more context to see if it can be done easier.

## EDIT

If I understood correctly your `func` looks like

```
def func(...):
    getattr(COMMANDS, cmd.command).command(irc_c, msg, cmd)
```

and you want to handle error from `getattr` call.

I can see next options here:

- Wrap [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) call in `try`-`except` and process `AttributeError` in-place

  ```
  def func(...):
      try:
          commander = getattr(COMMANDS, cmd.command)
      except AttributeError:
          print('Command {} not found'.format(cmd.command))
      else:
          commander.command(irc_c, msg, cmd)
  ```
- Wrap `getattr` call in `try`-`except`, re-raise a custom exception (or `ValueError`) and process it afterwards in OP `try`-`except`

  ```
  class CommandNotFound(Exception): pass


  def func(...):
      try:
          commander = getattr(COMMANDS, cmd.command)
      except AttributeError:
          raise CommandNotFound()  # or we can use `ValueError` instead
      else:
          commander.command(irc_c, msg, cmd)
  ```
- Use `default` parameter of `getattr` function and make some kind of logging there like

  ```
  class DefaultCommand:
      def command(self, irc_c, msg, cmd):
          print("Command {} is not found".format(cmd.command))
  ```

  and after that used like

  ```
  getattr(COMMANDS, cmd.command, DefaultCommand()).command(irc_c, msg, cmd)
  ```

Comment: These solutions are all really well thought-through. It's weird how seeing a try/except block makes me think of one specific way of doing things, but that limited mindset evidently does not apply to you

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to handle the specific error first. From more general to more specific, i.e `Exception => AttributeError => YourError`

```
>>> try:
...     raise MyCustomAttrErr("Hey, this failed!")
... except MyCustomAttrErr as e:
...     print(e)
... except AttributteError as e:
...     print("Attribute error raised")
... except Exception as e:
...     print("Base exception raised")
... 
Hey, this failed!
```

Python handled the `except` blocks in order from top to bottom and stops in the first block that captures it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but in this case `CustomError` is unrelated, I could just as easily swap that out for `ValueError` or anything else. This question relates to catching the *specific* `AttributeError`, which I'm currently detecting via analysis of `str(e)`.

Comment: @snazzybouche, in that case you can define an specific instance if the error str is always gonna be the same and use the `is` operator for example. Or declare an specific exception with that message and handle it the normal way. For any other thing I think you are missusing the exception handling.

Comment: I marked Azat's answer as correct, as it most correct for the question, but for this specific case I did end up using a `__getattr__` to raise a custom error. Thank you for your help.