# Python catching exception only if message matches

Tags: python, exception

**tl;dr**
How to catch different exceptions of the same type but with different messages?

**Situation**
In ideal world I would handle exceptions like this:

```py
try:
    do_something()
except ExceptionOne:
    handle_exception_one()
except ExceptionTwo:
    handle_exception_two()
except Exception as e:
    print("Other exception: {}".format(e))
```

But external code that I'm using can can throw, in my usage, two exceptions. Both are `ValueError`s but have different message. I'd like to differentiate handling them. This is the approach that I tried to take (for easier presentation of my idea I raise `AssertionError`):

```py
try:
    assert 1 == 2, 'test'
except AssertionError('test'):
    print("one")
except AssertionError('AssertionError: test'):
    print("two")
except Exception as e:
    print("Other exception: {}".format(e))
```

but this code always goes to the last `print()` and gives me

```
Other exception: test
```

Is there a way to catch exceptions this way? I'm assuming this is possible because Python lets me specify MESSAGE when catching exception `ExceptionType('MESSAGE')` but in practice I didn't manage to make it work. I also didn't find a definitive answer in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Catching specific exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531247/python-catching-specific-exception)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go for something like this:

```
 try:
     do_the_thing()
 except AssertionError as ae:
     if "message A" in ae.value:
        process_exception_for_message_A()
     elif "message B" in ae.value:
        process_exception_for_message_B()
     else:
        default_exception_precessing()
```

Comment: Yup, I wanted to avoid ifing for substrings but it seems like that's the only way to work around this problem. Thanks! :)